# Can we apply L'Hopital's rule where the derivative is not continuous?

Tags: limits, derivatives, continuity

My doubt arises due to the following :

We know that the definition of the derivative of a function at a point $x=a$, if it is differentiable at $a$, is:
$$f'(a) = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac {f(a+h) - f(a)}{h}$$

Suppose that the function $f(x)$ is differentiable in a finite interval $[c,d]$ and $a \in (c,d) $

So, we can apply L'Hopital's rule. On differentiating numerator and denominator with respect to $h$, we get:
$$f'(a) = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac {f(a+h) - f(a)}{h} = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac {f'(a+h)}{1}$$
Which implies that
$$f'(a) = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} f'(a+h)$$
Which means that the function $f'(x)$ is continuous at $x=a$

But this not necessarily true. A function may have a derivative everywhere but its derivative may not be continuous at some point. One of many counterexamples is:
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 \text{ ;    if x=0} \\ x^2 \sin \frac{1}{x} \text{;       if x $\neq$ 0 } \end{cases}$$
Whose derivative isn't continuous at $0$

So, is something wrong with what I have done ? Or is it necessary that for applying L'Hopital's rule, the function's derivative must be a continuous function?

If the latter is true, why does that condition appear in the proof for L'Hopital's rule ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case - yes, you need derivative to be continuous. In general, you need $\lim \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ to exist to apply L'Hospital's rule. As in your case $g'(x) = 1$, you proved that **if** there is a limit of $f'(a + h)$, then the limit is equal to $f'(a)$.

Answer (score 9):

L'Hospital's rule says under certain conditions: *IF* $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f'(h)}{g'(h)}=c$ exists, then also $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(h)}{g(h)}=c$. It does not say anything about the existence of the former limit.

Comment: @Dhvanit when $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f'(h)}{g'(h)}$ is one of $\pm\infty$, which some people classify as *not existing*, the implication also holds.

Comment: Basically, the condition mentioned in this answer means that applying L'Hospital's rule assumes that $\lim_{h\to 0}f'(a+h)$ exists. And if it exists, it can be shown that it must be $f'(a)$ (because derivatives need not be continuous, but still must fulfill the intermdiate value condition).

Comment: So, is it correct to say that : "If a function is continuous and differentiable in an interval, and if it's derivative is not continuous at $a$, then $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} f'(a+h)$ must not exist" ?  i.e.  Is it possible that in such a case, $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} f'(a+h) $ exists but isn't equal to $f'(a)$ ?

Comment: @Dhvanit: If $\lim_{h \to 0} f'(a+h)  $ exists, then by L'Hopital's rule, it is equal to $f'(a)$ and $f'$ is continuous at the point $a$. Hence if it is not continuousat the point $a$, then the limit does not exists! Observe also that $f'$ satisfies the intermediate value property by [Darboux's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis))

Answer (score 0):

The derivative value exists if: 
1. the left-side (-0) derivative exists
2. the right-side (+0) derivative exists
3. and they are the same/identical .

In your case they are not identical.