# Number of times I can use L'Hospitals Rule

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I was chatting with a bunch of friends in China and they were discussing the following question:
Suppose you're trying to compute the limit

$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}
$$

And given the second derivative of $f(x)$ EXISTS, how many times you can apply the L'Hospital's rule?
And the answer is only ONCE since the second derivative was not told to be continuous.

May I ask for elaboration for this? Is this answer sufficient to explain this?
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3181059/984872

Comment: Before addressing the regularity of $f''$, you first need to assure that $f'(0)=g'(0) = 0$ or $\lim_{x\to 0}f'(x) = \lim_{x\to 0}g'(x) = \infty$. So, in general, without checking that you still have an indetermination of the correct type after the first application of the rule, you cannot say you can apply twice.